# Odd Quirk with css margins

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure this one out. Its explained in the image.

[image]

As you can seem the margins are set as follows:

```
margin: -5px -5px 5px 5px;
```

However, for some reason, chrome is reading the right margin as -25px. Why is this happening?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a complete code example so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page? Maybe it's just a one time bug?'

Comment: Complete code sample that reproduces the issue is needed. Off the top of my head, I'd guess that a rule that looks like `margin: -5px -5px 5px 5px` is probably followed in the cascade by a rule that says `margin-right: -25px`

Comment: Is anything else changing the margin in your css or HTML? If something with higher priority is setting it after this that might be causing the issue.

Comment: @Nickknack still seems strange that this would be happening...even if the right margin was being overwritten.

Comment: @codedude Seems like it's a dev tools bug, regardless of the actual reason, although I can't replicate it with what I thought might be the issue.

Comment: @Adam true. This is what should be happening I believe... http://i.imgur.com/GWGIVRY.png

Comment: Adam is right. There is some rule that says `margin-right: -25px;`

Comment: @codedude - but what if you overwrote the `margin-right` property in the same selector that you specified the `margin` rule (`.test`) rather than in a different selector (`.other`)?

Comment: @Adam it gave the same result.

Comment: Which version of Chrome? I do get what you're seeing in Chromium 37 under Linux if I write `.test {margin:5px -5px 5px 5px; margin-right:-25px;}`. No line through any of the styles.

Comment: I'd meant to add, this is not the same in all versions of Chrome.